# When an exception is thrown and bubble up where a solution is found, how can we send the control back to where the exception was thrown?

Tags: php, exception, e-notices

For concreteness, I present some code, in which what I want, I know, is not possible.  I am looking for another way to get the same.

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); 

  function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
    // When $errno is a notice, we would like a way for the execution to continue here. Since it is only a notice, eventually it could go back to where the notice was triggered. 
  }

  set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

  Class TopLevelManagement {
    private $genericInfo = "Very important to add in notices"; 

    function highleveljob() {
      try{
        // In practice, the following statements could occur below in the execution tree, after a few other function calls. 
        $specific = new SpecificAndEncapsulated();
        $specific->specificjob();
      }
      catch (ErrorException $e) {
        $message = $e->getMessage() . $this->genericInfo; 
        mail($admin_email, "Consider the generic info and recover from this situation", $message); 
        // Here we would like the execution to continue where the exception was thrown. In the real world, this would be like "thank you error handler for SpecificAndEncapsulated::specificjob, we have taken care of the issue with the help of our larger perspective.". 
      }   
    } 
  }

  Class SpecificAndEncapsulated {

    function specificjob() {
      // Some processing
      if($unexpected == true) trigger_error('Here is how little I know, as I should', E_USER_NOTICE);
      // Continue as expected after a notice.
    }
  }
?>
```

Of course, one solution is to pass `$genericInfo` as a parameter or as a global variable to `SpecificAndEncapsulated::justdomyjob` and let the error_handler take care of the issue without bubbling up any exception. However, this solution is not natural. There are other ways to systematically  pass the variable `$genericInfo`  to `SpecificAndEncapsulated`, but the issue will be the same.  There should be no need to systematically pass the $genericInfo value, because it is not something that should concern `SpecificAndEncapsulated`, not even when an exception occurs, even less systematically at every call.   A communication back to the issuer of the exception saying "thanks, now continue", after a notice has been managed at an higher level, is natural. Is there a support for this type of E_NOTICE or E_USER_NOTICE management?

Comment: The title is misleading, because I would be happy with another approach that does not use exceptions. A better formulation of the question would have been "Is there a way to throw a notice as we throw an exception, except that after it bubbles up where a solution is found, we can send the control back to where the notice was thrown?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions, by design, are errors after which normal execution cannot continue.

In the real world, it would go like this: a police officer (third party) calls a trucking company dispatcher (the top-level code) and says, "one of your trucks exploded in a ball of fire and the driver is in the hospital" (the job), and the dispatcher says "Noted. I expect the payload to arrive on schedule."

You have to catch exceptions inside the job if you want to continue the job. One viable approach is to pass an error handler function or a delegate object into the job.

Comment: Since this answered the question as it shows in the title, despite the fact that it was not what I had in mind, I decided to pick this as the answer. The question that I had in mind was is there some kind of well established approaches or some buitin features to manage  "thrown notices" instead of thrown exceptions. The difference being that the control should return to the normal execution after a "thrown notice" is catched.  My bet is that there is none and every one has to develop his own approach using regular language structures.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5 has an exception model similar to that of other programming languages. An exception can be thrown, and caught ("catched") within PHP. Code may be surrounded in a try block, to facilitate the catching of potential exceptions. Each try must have at least one corresponding catch block. Multiple catch blocks can be used to catch different classes of exceptions. Normal execution (when no exception is thrown within the try block, or when a catch matching the thrown exception's class is not present) will continue after that last catch block defined in sequence. Exceptions can be thrown (or re-thrown) within a catch block.

When an exception is thrown, code following the statement will not be executed, and PHP will attempt to find the first matching catch block. If an exception is not caught, a PHP Fatal Error will be issued with an "Uncaught Exception ..." message, unless a handler has been defined with set_exception_handler().

In PHP 5.5 and later, a finally block may also be specified after the catch blocks. Code within the finally block will always be executed after the try and catch blocks, regardless of whether an exception has been thrown, and before normal execution resumes.

The thrown object must be an instance of the Exception class or a subclass of Exception. Trying to throw an object that is not will result in a PHP Fatal Error.

Comment: As I said, I only used this code to explain what I want.  I know that, after a catched exception, the execution continues after the last catch block or finally block - it is not returned where the exception was thrown.   I just need something different, which I feel is also very natural. Having to pass a delegate object (as proposed by Leonid) to every function that might need to "throw" a notice is kind of ugly.  So, I was hoping that a builtin feature supports that natural need.

Comment: I should perhaps edit the question title. I think it is misleading, since clearly the answer is simply "NO, it is not possible with exceptions"  What I want is a way to achieve the same.